# hyperlink inside li element

Tags: jquery, html, css

is there a way to stretch the hyplerlink element to the size of a li element inside

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">this link to fill up the li element width and height</a><li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can select the best answer that helps you. It will hardly takes few seconds... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a {display: block; width: 100%;}
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Apply `display:block;width:100%` to the element's CSS.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS** (using selectors - a little trickier but fun)

```
ul>li>a {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

The `<a>` tag is an `inline` element, which means that its width can't be styled (and also several other properties).  So, the display needs to be changed to `block`.

Comment: I was on the fly with my answer, I actually agree with this standards-wise more than my own answer. You've done a good job at explaining it too :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure

```
li a {width:100%; display:block;}
```